# An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding EnableRetryOnFailure

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to run my ASP.NET Core-6 Web API project on the local machine, But I got this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure' to the 'UseSqlServer' call.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteAsync>d__7`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.<ExistsAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.<MigrateAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at WebApi.Program.<Main>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\HP\MyAppWebApi\Program.cs:line 40

Inner Exception 1:
SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)

Inner Exception 2:
Win32Exception: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

It highlights throw in the class below:

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

            try
            {
                var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

                if (context.Database.IsSqlServer())
                {
                    await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
                }

                var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
                var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

                await ApplicationDbContextSeed.SeedDefaultUserAsync(userManager, roleManager);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while migrating or seeding the database.");

                throw;
            }
        }
        await host.RunAsync();
    }
}
```

This is the line 40 it compalins about:

> await context.Database.MigrateAsync();

What could be wrong with the code and how do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you already checked the points from Inner Exception 1?

Answer (score 1):

Check the database name on the appsettings.json file.

and recheck the table name and model name. weather it's matched or not

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).